# How to finish a second task with activiti bpmn?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

There are 2 task started in parallel: `ManagerReviewTask` and `DirectorReviewTask`.

When:

- `DirectorReviewTask` finished first, `ManagerReviewTask` should be finished too (programatically).
- `ManagerReviewTask` finished first, workflow should wait until `DirectorReviewTask` is finished by assigned user.

How do I do that? Could you please provide an example with activiti xml?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would add a listener to `DirectorReviewTask` and finish `ManagerReviewTask`.

```
<userTask id="DirectorReviewTask" name="DirectorReviewTask">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="listeners.DirectorReviewTaskListener"/>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

Here the listner class:

```
public class DirectorReviewTaskListener implements TaskListener {

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
        if (TaskListener.EVENTNAME_COMPLETE.equals(delegateTask.getEventName())) {
            String executionId = delegateTask.getExecutionId();
            Task managerReviewTask = taskService.createTaskQuery().executionId(executionId).taskName("ManagerReviewTask").singleResult();
            if (managerReviewTask != null) {
                taskService.complete(managerReviewTask.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think you should end up with a parallel gateway:

```
<parallelGateway id="fork" />
<sequenceFlow sourceRef="fork" targetRef="ManagerReviewTask" />
<sequenceFlow sourceRef="fork" targetRef="DirectorReviewTask" />

<userTask id="ManagerReviewTask" name="ManagerReviewTask" />
<sequenceFlow sourceRef="ManagerReviewTask" targetRef="join" />

<userTask id="DirectorReviewTask" name="DirectorReviewTask">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="listeners.DirectorReviewTaskListener"/>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
<sequenceFlow sourceRef="DirectorReviewTask" targetRef="join" />

<parallelGateway id="join" />
<sequenceFlow sourceRef="join" targetRef="GO_FROM_HERE" />
```

Comment: how can i get taskService service in java?

Answer (score 2):

A rather standard pattern. A standard inclusive gateway and a signal to cancel.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add xml representation too?

Answer (score 1):

From BPMN perspective you have to possibilities to choose from:

1. After DirectorReviewTask (or as ending event for it) add send signal (lets say stopManagerReviewTask). On ManagerReviewTask you need to add handling of stopManagerReviewTask as Boundary interrupting signal event.
2. If DirectorReviewTask is the last action in the process, end the flow containing DirectorReviewTask with End terminate event.

In case 1 you only need to consider how to force activiti to stop only one DirectorReviewTask from the same process not all instances running in parallel.